# Are SERIALIZABLE deadlocks avoided or just detected?

Tags: deadlock, isolation-level

SERIALIZABLE is the highest standard isolation level. It avoids dirty reads, phantoms,... by ensuring that, whatever happens, the ultimate result of a transaction schedule is equal to the result of a completely sequential schedule. However, deadlocks can occur.

My question is, can deadlocks be avoided even when using the SERIALIZABLE level?

Classical OS/distributed systems theory suggets you can prevent deadlocks by removing one of the main conditions, such as circular dependencies.

Do common relational databases (such as MySQL, Postgres or SQL Server) prevent deadlocks or do they just detect them?